# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-http

I'm struggling to see how these type errors could be resolved in Flutter.

I am making an HTTP request to a server which responds with the following JSON:

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "email": ["Email is required"]
  }
}
```

I am assigning the data from the response like so:

```
Future login(String email, String password) async {
    ...
    Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);

    final List<String> emailErrors = data['errors']['email'];
    final List<String> passwordErrors = data['errors']['password'];
}
```

Once I try to do that I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'

It seems like using type `dynamic` it will pretty much throw an error if you try to set a type annotation afterwards for any type. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the `data['errors']['email']`returns a `List<dynamic>`.

You have to cast items to `String` like that :

`final List<String> emailErrors = data['errors']['email'].cast<String>()`

Comment: Every element, even the nested ones will be inferred as the dynamic type because that’s what I annotated in my map?

Comment: Exactly, all elements